# How can I save HighCharts image into the project folder in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, save

Im using highcharts to display some results, but i need to save the chart as an jpg image into the project folder to email it.

There is a way to save the image without involve the "download" of the browser, just save it to a destinated folder.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you propose to save it if you do not download it? If you have your own export server setup you can do this via command line but you have to be on the server with the export app.

Comment: i mean without the download "feature" of the browser, like if you were downloading a file. Just that when the chart is created save it into the project folder without the user notice.

Comment: How do you propose to save it from the web page where it is rendered without downloading it?

Comment: Well, it has to be something, i have read about the export property but i do not know how to use it exactly. I have tried but i don't make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your own export server like what is described [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) (I use the Java + phantomJS setup). You can then send via the command line the json to build the chart and the output type (jpeg, pdf, etc) and then you can redirect this output to a folder of your choice. You cannot do this from the web automagically as the code does not know your path to the folder you want to store the image in. For that see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside).

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible. The source code for the server-side export processing is available here:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/php/php-batik/index.php

It's essentially getting a java program called Batik to stream out a PNG, JPG or PDF version of the file that you submitted. You could very easily modify that PHP code to save the batik output to a local file on the server rather than streaming it back to the user.

More info on exactly how the server-side exporting works is here:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Hope this helps! Enjoy!