# HighChart Graph not displaying in Mail

Tags: javascript, html, email, highcharts

I used Highchart graph to be sent as a report through email. The text is getting displayed, but not the graph. When viewing through the browser option, I could see the graph.
What is the issue? Any setting should I enable to embed it or any script embedding should be done?

[image: This is the Highchart graph in the email. I could view it in the browser and not in the Gmail or outlook]

Comment: In addition to what @AgeDeO wrote, to export chart as an image, you can use Highcharts export module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript in mail is not going to work. You'll have to save the highchart chart as an image on your webserver and link to it as an image in the e-mail.

[How can I save HighCharts image into the project folder in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166403/how-can-i-save-highcharts-image-into-the-project-folder-in-php)